# Show marker popup on OSM when I click - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm doing a simple Web App with *Open Street Maps* and some markers on it. Now I'd like to show a different popup with some information about the marker when I click on each one, but I don't get how to do it properly.

I'm using Angular 7 and in the HTML file I'm only showing the map.

In the Ts file this is my code at the moment:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var ol: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  latitude = 40.423533061444374;
  longitude = -3.7045899778604507;

  map: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: {
          collapsible: false
        }
      }),
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-3.7045899778604507, 40.423533061444374]),
        zoom: 13
      })
    });

    const markers = [
      { lat: 40.433533061444374, lng: -3.7145899778604507 },
      { lat: 40.4135330614443741, lng: -3.7045899778604507 }
    ];
    const features = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      const m = markers[i];
      const longitude = m.lng;
      const latitude = m.lat;

      const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([longitude, latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
      });

      const iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: 'http://cdn.mapmarker.io/api/v1/pin?text=P&size=40&hoffset=1'
        }))
      });

      iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
      features.push(iconFeature);

    }

    const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: features
    });

    const markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
    });

    this.map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);

  }
}
```

Comment: it has been a while since i worked with OSM last time, but generally those markers will be embedded into HTML elements which IDs you should know. Since you are using Angur you should consider using something like this: https://github.com/toutpt/angular-osm#readme   DOM Handling in third party libraries using expressions like `document.selectElementById` in an angular context is a strong antipattern.